# Outputting child nodes to CSV with Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, xml-parsing

Edit: I've replaced the example XML with real data and provided my code at the bottom.

I have several xml-files containing from 1 to 10+ lines of the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cec="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd">
   <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="DKK">2586.61</cbc:PayableAmount>
   </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
   <cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="HUR">1.50</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="DKK">1633.65</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
   <cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="HUR">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="DKK">952.96</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

And I want to output the data to a CSV-file in the following structure:

```
filename,lineId,lineQuantity,lineAmount,payableAmount
file1,1,1.50,1633.65,2586.61
file1,2,1.00,952.96,2586.61
file2,.,.,.
```

...where there's a row for each line per file coupled with the filename and total amount.

This is my code:

```
from os import listdir, path, walk
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

def invoicelines(self):
    filename = path.splitext(path.split(file)[1])[0]
    lineId = root.find('./InvoiceLine/ID').text
    lineQuantity = root.find('./InvoiceLine/InvoicedQuantity').text
    lineAmount = root.find('./InvoiceLine/LineExtensionAmount').text
    payableAmount = root.find('./LegalMonetaryTotal/PayableAmount').text

    row = [
        filename,
        lineId,
        lineQuantity,
        lineAmount,
        payableAmount
        ]

    return row

csvfile = 'output.csv'

def csv_write_header(csvfile):
     with open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
          writer = csv.writer(outfile)
          writer.writerow([
               'filename',
               'lineId',
               'lineQuantity',
               'lineAmount',
               'payableAmount'
               ])

xml_files = []
for root, dirs, files in walk('mypath'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            xml_files.append(path.join(root, file))
            csv_write_header(csvfile)

for file in xml_files:
    tree = ET.iterparse(file)
    for _, el in tree:
        el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1] # ignores namespaces
    root = tree.root
    if 'Invoice' in root.tag: # only invoice files
        for e in root.iter('InvoiceLine'):
            with open(csvfile, 'a', newline='') as outfile:
                writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                writer.writerow(invoicelines(e))
```

And the output I get if I just parse the above file is:

```
filename,lineId,lineQuantity,lineAmount,payableAmount
file1,1,1.50,1633.65,2586.61
file1,1,1.50,1633.65,2586.61
```

...so I'm guessing it's something with my iteration.

Comment: TotalAmount is set once at the beginning of each file ?

Comment: Yes. If that presents problems it could be omitted, as I'm primarily interested in the lines.

Answer (score 2):

The following code achieves your desired result.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def extract_line_id_data(line_element):
    line_id = line_element[0].text
    quantity = line_element[1].text
    line_amount = line_element[2].text

    return line_id, quantity, line_amount


# Iterate over all files in a directory
for _, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to_folder/with/xml_files/'):
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as output:
        output.write('Filename,LineID,Quantity,LineAmount,TotalAmount\n')  # Headers
        for xml_file in files:
            # If not all files in the folder files are XML you'll need to catch an exception here
            tree = ET.parse(xml_file)  # might need to use os.path.abspath
            root = tree.getroot()
            total_amount = root[0][0].text  # Get total amount value
            # Iterate over all "Line" elements
            for e in root[1:]:
                output.write('{},{},{},{},{}\n'.format(xml_file, * extract_line_id_data(e), total_amount))
```

Tested with your file and a "file2.xml" with a `TotalAmount` of 350, output looks like this:

```
Filename,LineID,Quantity,LineAmount,TotalAmount
file.xml,1,4,132,407
file.xml,2,1,72,407
file.xml,3,7,203,407
file2.xml,1,4,132,350
file2.xml,2,1,72,350
file2.xml,3,7,203,350
```

I hope this works for you. I have used ElementTree as preferred, although I would have used `lxml` myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I keep getting out of range errors with the function, so I edited the lines to include the path of the elements e.g. root.find('./Line/LineID'), but now it only returns the values from first elements, so my output looks like this: file.xml,1,4,132,407, file.xml,1,4,132,407 ect. (the correct number of lines, but with the output of the first line). Hope it makes sense!

Comment: @chrlindgaard I'll need to see more code to understand the problem exactly, consider editing your question and adding it there.

Comment: I've edited my question now. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2

{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\text.csv";
        static void Main()
        {

            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp", "*.xml");
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);

            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

                string amount = (string)doc.Descendants("TotalAmount").FirstOrDefault();

                foreach (XElement line in doc.Descendants("Line"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",",
                        filename,
                        (string)line.Element("LineID"),
                        (string)line.Element("Quantity"),
                        (string)line.Element("LineAmount"),
                        amount));
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: That's some funky looking Python ;-)